# Can't reach jupyter docker container from host machine

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook

I have a question about the https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/scipy-notebook . I'm trying to run this image with docker-compose:

compose:

```
  jupyter:
    container_name: jupyter
    build: 
      context: ./Jupyter
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
       - ./scripts:/opt/notebooks/connector
    network_mode: "host"
    command: bash -c "jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip=* --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook
EXPOSE 8888
```

and I can't reach it with http://locahost:8888 .... url. I'm using windows 10 as host machine and tried reach other services from this docker compose and these work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the host network mode and publish ports together

```sh
docker run --rm -it --net=host -p80:80 yeasy/simple-web:latest
```

WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode

For the second part,
to reach the host from inside the container, use `host.docker.internal` dns

Comment: I'm trying to reach container from the host.

Comment: You will be able to publish ports to host if you are not using network_mode=host. As you already know, your application will be available on 8888. Inside the container, when you need a service running on host machine, change the endpoint to host.docker.internal

Comment: The problem there because network_mode: "host" if I remove it - everything work. But I need to have an ability to reach host machine from this container. I know only this way for reach it

Comment: To reach host from container, use IP of the host. It can be checked using ifconfig/ipconfig command, based on your distro flavor. 
Docker for Mac/Windows gives a shorthand dns to find the ip of docker machine: `host.docker.internal`
To validate, inside container run `curl host.docker.internal`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `build` section with `image: jupyter/scipy-notebook`. Also remove `network_mode` and `command` sections, and your code may work. I don't know why your code is not running in this situation, but I think it must be related to the `command` section, which is replacing the default command of the jupyter image. Furthermore, you don't need to create a Dockerfile to just add EXPOSE; you can use the image directly.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The problem there because `network_mode: "host"` if I remove it - everything work. But I need to have an ability to reach host machine from this container. I know only this way for reach it.

Comment: So leave ```network_mode: host``` and remove the ```ports``` section. They should not be used together, because they can conflict with each other.